# Import Excel as List Fails

Tags: list, excel, import

I have an Excel Spreadsheet that I want to import into SharePoint 2010 as a list but upon doing so I receive the following errors.  As a work around I have saved the spreadsheet as csv and then converted it back to xls but the error persists.

[image]

```
---------------------------
Microsoft Forms
---------------------------
Could not load an object because it is not available on this machine.


---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------


---------------------------
Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications
---------------------------
Compile error:

The code in this project must be updated for use on 64-bit systems.  Please review and update Declare statements and then mark them with the PtrSafe attribute.
---------------------------
OK   Help   
---------------------------


---------------------------
Message from webpage
---------------------------
An unexpected error has occurred.  (-2147352567)
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

Comment: P.S. My client is Office 2010 on Windows 7 64bit

Comment: It looks like Excel is doing something like trying to load a 32bit kernel something or other.  My machine is 64bit so that is really odd.

Comment: What's with the macro?